# GET Variables Show Up in URL on .htaccess Rewrite of URLs That Don't Terminate with /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with my rewrites exposing GET variables if the originating request isn't terminated with a forward slash (/).

Here's my rule:

```
# All requests are routed to PHP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework/index.php?framework=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

If I visit:

http://www.domain.com/folder/

everything works great. If I visit:

http://www.domain.com/folder

I get redirected to:

http://www.domain.com/folder/?framework=folder

What gives?

Comment: do u have any other RewriteRule that we should be aware of ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `/folder` exists in your web root. Since you haven't sent Apache a slash-terminated URL, and the requested resource is a folder, the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive forces a redirect to the corrected URL.

Unfortunately, `mod_rewrite` has a go at your request before this redirect occurs, and while it doesn't change the URI that is used in generating the redirect, the changes that it makes to the query string are not separated in a way that `mod_dir` knows not to include them. Therefore, when the redirect is sent back to the browser, it includes the query string generated by your `RewriteRule`.

A potential solution to this (other than turning off `DirectorySlash`, which is not recommended for the reasons listed in the documentation) is to perform `mod_dir`'s work for it as part of your rule set:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteRule [^/]$ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ framework/index.php?framework=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Tim, you are legit. Thanks for the awesome response and code. Is there anyway to make the http:// portion of the redirect dynamic? (it may be https)

Comment: @Kirk - No problem. I think what I've just edited in should take care of the http/https problem, but let me know if you run into issues.